# TypoScript includeJS render order. Difference between 6.2 and 7.6?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Was there a change in the handling of includeJS between the Versions 6.2 and 7.6 in the rendering order?

We've updated a TYPO3 6.2 instance with about 70 js files included. The order of the js files is different now. Most of the files are included by includeJS.stringKey=file.js. Also includeJSlibs and includeJSFooter are used.

Let's assume the order of the static template includes is the same, schould the render order of the js files change.

Answer (score 2):

I see this post is a few days old but I had a similar problem and here comes a solution for at least parts of your problem:

I can't tell you something about the changes between the versions but: For every block of css or js-inclusion there is the possibility to use the parameter forceOnTop.

```
page.includeJSFooter.1 = /fileadmin/js/jquery.min.js
page.includeJSFooter.1.forceOnTop = 1
```

With this possibility you could at last with triumph with one file in one block or over extension-included scripts.

With the TypoScriptparameter

```
config.moveJsFromHeaderToFooter = 1
```

you get the rendered following order in the footer (Typo3 7.6):

First includeJSLibs:

```
page.includeJSLibs.XYZ
page.includeJSLibs.XYZ.forceOnTop = 1
page.includeJSLibs.1
...
page.includeJSLibs.9xyz9
```

then comes includeJS

```
page.includeJS.ABC
page.includeJS.ABC.forceOnTop = 1
page.includeJS.cba
...
page.includeJS.abc
```

and then includeJSFooter

```
page.includeJSFooter.xy = ...
page.includeJSFooter.xy.forceOnTop = 1
page.includeJSFooter.1
...
page.includeJSFooter.x1x2y3
```

Without the "moveJsFromHeaderToFooter" includeJS and includeJSLibs are rendered in the header.

I hope this helps to order your inclusions at last partially.

Comment: Thank you - this obviously a Typo3 bug as old as Typo3.